# Javascript: Determining the number of consecutive days (streak) in an array

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am trying to write a function that gets an array of dates (potentially unsorted, date_array) as input and determines the number of consecutive days that are in the array from a certain date (start_date) backwards, not including the start date.

```
Example:
start_date = 23.01.2023

date_array = [
01.01.2023,
02.01.2023,
20.01.2023, <- day 3 of the streak
21.01.2023, <- day 2 of the streak
22.01.2023, <- day 1 of the streak
22.01.2023, <- day 1 of the streak
23.01.2023,
24.01.2023]

Result:
streak_lenght: 3 days
```

The function I implemented is supposed to create a date range from the start date backwards and count, how many dates in the array are within the range. Every loop, the end date of the range goes one day further into the past. The loop continues as long as the number of dates within the range grow.

start date ... start date - 1 day
start date ... start date - days

However, for some reason the start date gets overwritten by the end date before the while loop starts...

I would greatly appreciate any help - or suggestions for better solutions to the problem. Thanks in advance!

```
const dateArray = [
  new Date("2022-12-31"), 
  new Date("2023-01-02"), // day 3 of streak
  new Date("2023-01-03"), // day 2 of streak 
  new Date("2023-01-03"), // day 2 of streak
  new Date("2023-01-04"), // day 1 of streak
  new Date("2023-01-05")];

const d_start = new Date("2023-01-05");

function currentStreak(dateArray, d_start) {
    // dateArray: Array of dates on which event was executed
    // d_start: start date of the streak, not included

    // Create a range d_start ... d_end, d_end starts one day before d_start

    let d_end = d_start
    d_end.setDate(d_start.getDate() - 1)
    let countPrev = -1
    let count = 0
    let streakCount = 0

    // Count how many array elements are in the range and continue loop while this number increases    
    while (count > countPrev) {
        countPrev = count
        // count number of array elements between start and end date
        count = dateArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
          if((d_start > currentValue) && (currentValue > d_end))
          {
            accumulator += 1
          }
         return accumulator
        }, 0)
        // set new end date for next iteration
        d_end = d_end.setDate(d_end.getDate() - 1)
        streakCount = streakCount+1
    }
    return count;
  }

currentStreak(dateArray, d_start)
```

Comment: So, if `dateArray.indexOf("2023-01-04") == -1` or `dateArray.indexOf("2023-01-06") == -1`, the streak is 0?

Answer (score 0):

> However, for some reason the start date gets overwritten by the end
> date before the while loop starts...

That's what happens when you use `setDate`: it mutates the date.

Wouldn't a reducer be sufficient?

[**edit** based on comment] I have a [small library](https://github.com/KooiInc/DateDifferenceCalculator) to calculate the difference between 2 dates available. In the stackoverflow snippet this can not be loaded via the javascript panel, so here's a snippet using a script (type module) in the html panel, making use of that library.

```html
<script type="module">
  const diffCalc = (await 
    import("//kooiinc.github.io/DateDifferenceCalculator/index.js")).default();
  const dateArray = [
    new Date("2022-12-31"),
    new Date("2023-01-02"), // day 3 of streak
    new Date("2023-01-03"), // day 2 of streak 
    new Date("2023-01-03"), // day 2 of streak
    new Date("2023-01-04"), // day 1 of streak
    new Date("2023-01-05") ];


  const streak = dateArray.reverse()
    .reduce( (acc, d, i, self) => {
      const diff = i && diffCalc(d, self[i-1]);
      return diff && `${diff}`.startsWith(`1 day`)
        ? [...acc, d] : acc;
     }, [] );

  console.log(`Streak length: ${
    streak.length}\nStreak values: ${
    JSON.stringify(streak, null, 2)}`);
</script>
```

Comment: Would this break if the streak crossed a month boundary?

Comment: @ray:  it wouldn't *break*, but that may give unexpected results. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So here we say a day gap < 26Hrs.

Push all runs to the accumulator and then pop the result.

```js
const dateArray = [
  new Date("2022-12-31"), 
  new Date("2023-01-02"), // day 3 of streak
  new Date("2023-01-03"), // day 2 of streak 
  new Date("2023-01-03"), // day 2 of streak
  new Date("2023-01-04"), // day 1 of streak
  new Date("2023-01-05")]
  
// 26Hrs is 9.36e+7;

const streak = dateArray.reduce((p,day,i,arr) => {
    if ( arr[i+1]?.valueOf() == day.valueOf() ) return p;
    if ( arr[i+1]?.valueOf() - day.valueOf() <  9.36e+7 ) { 
      p[p.length - 1].push(arr[i+1]); 
    } else { 
      p.push([]) 
    }
    return p;
},[]).sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length).pop()

console.log({ streak })
```